# How can I ensure at least one checkbox is checked in a particular div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div class="answer" id="yesOptions">` and I need to check that at least 1 checkbox inside this particular  is checked.  If not, I need to return `alert('At least 1 checkbox must be checked from this div!');`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
var checkedboxes = $('#yesOptions :checkbox:checked').length;

if (checkedboxes === 0){
    alert('At least 1 checkbox must be checked from this div!');
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/f8UhA/

Comment: I deleted my answer, yours is great.

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gvbX5/

You can use grouping, like sample code below and demo above, hope it helps the cause.

Good links:

[What is the proper way to uncheck a checkbox in jQuery 1.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950123/what-is-the-proper-way-to-uncheck-a-checkbox-in-jquery-1-7)

[JQuery - is at least one checkbox checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941746/jquery-is-at-least-one-checkbox-checked)

**code**

```
$('input').change(function() {
    if ($("[name=group1]:checked").length > 0){

    }else{
        alert('select atleast one checkbox');
    }
});

 if ($("[name=group1]:checked").length == 0)
        alert('select atleast one checkbox');


<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="3" />​
​
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("input[type=checkbox]:checked", $("#yesOptions")).length` will give you the count of checkboxes that is checked within that div.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just do:

```
if (!$("[type='checkbox']", "#yesOptions").is(':checked'))​ 
    alert('At least 1 checkbox must be checked from this div!');​
```

[FIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/D6QUp/)

[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/D6QUp/1/)