# jQuery uncheck checkbox if text input has length

Tags: jquery, validation

I need to un check a checkbox (if it has been checked) if another text input has a value (M/DD/YYY format). I am using glDatePicker to set the value for #StartDate, the content brought in via ajax so Im using the '.on' funciton

```
<div id="bottomContent">
    <input type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate"><br />
    <input type="text" id="EndDate" name="EndDate"><br />
    <label for="AllDate"><input type="checkbox" name="AllDate" id="AllDate">All Dates</label>
</div>

$(function() {
    $('#bottomContent').on('change', '#StartDate', function(e){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if ( value.length > 0  ) {
        //$('#AllDate').prop('checked', false);
        console.log('hi');
        }
    });
});
```

Im pretty sure i have my parameters messed up in the .on arguments.

Comment: $('#AllDate').removeProp('checked');

Comment: `$('#AllDate')[0].checked = $(this).val().length > 0;`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? If I check the box, type in the top field and then click outside of it, the checkbox gets unchecked: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PUzZw/. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: your code works http://jsfiddle.net/Xkvcx/1/

Comment: I need it to uncheck the checkbox as soon as a value is entered in #StartDate not on blur. Im using version 1.8.2 and am using the glDatePicker to get value into #StartDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! here you go, since you're using glDatePicker.

I have modified the jsfiddle to do so as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xkvcx/8/

```
$(function() {
    $('#StartDate').glDatePicker({
        onClick: (function(el, cell, date, data) {
            el.val(date.toLocaleDateString());
            $('#AllDate').prop('checked', false);
        })
    });
});
```

using this script, whenever you select a selectable date, it will remove the checkbox from AllDate

and obviously this all came from this reference: http://glad.github.com/glDatePicker/#reference

Thank you and good night!

Comment: Lo siento Pedro, y gracias.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign no te funciono?

Comment: si te ayudo, marcalo como respuesta plis y gracias

Comment: por supuesto, muchas gracias Pedro.

Answer (score 1):

The `.prop('checked', false)` should work as expected. Try uncommenting the line, and it should work (see fiddle link below).

```
$(function() {
    $('#bottomContent').on('change', '#StartDate', function(e){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if ( value.length > 0  ) {
             $('#AllDate').prop('checked', false);
        console.log('hi');
        }
    });
});
```

I have previously recommended to use `.removeProp()`, [but I'm mistaken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950123/what-is-the-proper-way-to-uncheck-a-checkbox-in-jquery-1-7).

See fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/Xkvcx/

Comment: According to http://api.jquery.com/removeprop/ .removeProp should not be used to remove checked. (because it is totally removed and can't be added back again.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#StartDate').on('change', function(e){
    $('#AllDate')[0].checked = $(this).val().length > 0;
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Yesy/)

---

Or, if you are updating `#bottomContent` with AJAX and need to keep the `.on()` binding the same:

```
$('#bottomContent').on('change', '#StartDate', function(e){
    $('#AllDate')[0].checked = $(this).val().length > 0;
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Yesy/2/)

Comment: Nothing seems to work in my case. If I check the checkbox, then (by date picker) put a value in #StartDate, it is not clearing the #AllDate checkbox. I can log the value of the input - not sure if the date picker is screwing it up

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign: The examples I've provided are a "virgin scenario" and work. So, given the most basic implementation works, are you sure you don't have any other scripts competing with the bindings?

Comment: I apologize if my communication isn't clear. In your example, if you check the checkbox, THEN click in #StartDate and bring up datepicker and select a date it is not un checking the checkbox, which is what I need.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign: Just change the condition then. `.checked = $(this).val() == 0` (See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8Yesy/3/))